# Don't exclude results that have punctuation just because the query doesn't

Tags: bug, search

The <strike>new</strike> search function allows quoted queries that include punctuation, and this is fantastic, most of the time. However, the search considers the punctuation as part of the word itself, so searches for `"a test"` will not show results containing `a test,`, `a test.`, or `a test?`. The reverse is also true.

Is this the intended behavior ? <--(space added so that `behavior` will show in results.)

It seems that the logical way to do fix this (while maintaining character search) is for queries *with* punctuation to match results *with* punctuation, while queries *without* punctuation to match either with *and* without.

---

Example: ["Thank you Jeff Atwood!"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Thank+you+Jeff+Atwood%21%22) vs ["Thank you Jeff Atwood"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Thank+you+Jeff+Atwood%22)

A more practical example is described in Arjan's answer below.

Comment: This behavior seems intentional so that [searches for punctuation are actually *possible*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32879/135887).

Comment: @Charles, I know, but it seems to me that this should not be used to exclude relevant results. If I search for `"and this is fantastic"` this question will not come up, since I omitted the comma after "fantastic". This is a negative behavior, IMO.

Comment: IMO that's a bug if only because you didn't search "a test ", that punctuation is separate from the part in quotes.

Comment: Do you think the results should contain "a tested" or "a testaverde"?

Comment: @Some: No. Stemming should only occur on non-quoted queries. I'm saying that punctuation is a special case that should be treated differently by search. It would seem to me that the logical way to do it is that quoted searches that _have_ punctuation should bring up results that have punctuation, while searches without punctuation should bring up results with _and_ without.

Comment: Another reported example: [search for "StackOverflowException"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange/161897#161897) which in the actual posted stack trace will have a *leading* dot.

Answer (score 22):

This also makes searching for exact error messages hard, even more so if the message is quoted in the post itself:

- ["This answer was marked as spam or offensive"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22This+answer+was+marked+as+spam+or+offensive%22) does not get one [the Recent Feature Changes FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) in the result, as that happens to include a longer quoted text:

  > [...] the following text: "This answer was marked as spam or offensive and is therefore not shown - you can see the revision history for details". Where [...]
- ["An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in Unknown Module"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22An+unhandled+exception+of+type+%27System.StackOverflowException%27+occurred+in+Unknown+Module%22) yields 0 results.
- ["An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in Unknown Module."](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22An+unhandled+exception+of+type+%27System.StackOverflowException%27+occurred+in+Unknown+Module.%22) yields 1 result:

  > [...] got error.
  >
  > An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in Unknown Module. anyhint regards,
- ["unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in Unknown"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22unhandled+exception+of+type+%27System.StackOverflowException%27+occurred+in+Unknown%22) yields 3 results, as 2 of those 3 posts have quotes around the error in the post itself, which makes matching fail even when including the trailing dot in the search:

  > [...] every single time, I end up with the same error
  >
  > > "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in Unknown Module."
  >
  > with a [...]
- Google+ related searches are hard; neither ["Know who you are on Google"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Know+who+you+are+on+Google%22) nor ["Know who you are on Google+"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Know+who+you+are+on+Google%2B%22) find [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18329629/scope-to-get-email-address-alone) that holds:

  > [...] prompts the user:
  >
  > > The app would like to:
  > >
  > > - Know who you are on Google+

But also without any quotes, searching error messages is difficult:

- ["Your edit couldn't be submitted. Please see the error above."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Your+edit+couldn%27t+be+submitted.+Please+see+the+error+above.%22) correctly showed 2 results.
- [Your edit couldn't be submitted. Please see the error above.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=Your+edit+couldn%27t+be+submitted.+Please+see+the+error+above.) (without quotes) did not show any results in February 2013, though at least two questions hold that text exactly like that, also without any quotes:

  1. [Make error notifications in posts more obvious/visible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167588/make-error-notifications-in-posts-more-obvious-visible)
  2. ["Please see the error above" but error is inconspicuous](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167934/please-see-the-error-above-but-error-is-inconspicuous)

  After I added some SEO terms to the first, at least that first is found. I'm not sure if adding the text `couldnt` to the question, without the apostrophe, helped finding it. Note how `couldnt` without the apostrophe is highlighted, while `couldn't` is not, but maybe highlighting is unrelated here:

  [image] <sub>(And yes, the excerpt shows text in a different order than the actual post...!)</sub>

As an aside:

- [Your edit **couldnt** be submitted. Please see the error above.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=Your+edit+couldnt+be+submitted.+Please+see+the+error+above.) does not find the second post.

Comment: As regards your aside, I've already asked about it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164674/search-queries-in-quotes-are-ignored-in-the-results-excerpts

Comment: Nice, @HodofHod. But apparently only when there are ignored words. (Cleaned up my answer; commented about the ignored word to your bug report.)