# "Please see the error above" but error is inconspicuous

Tags: bug, edits, error-message

I tried to improve a question, but it got rejected with a message:

> Your edit couldn't be submitted. Please see the error above.

And the page auto-scrolled up a bit.

It took me a while to notice the error message, because (a) it was placed on top of a (similarly colored) advertisement, and (b) because it was in an area of the page (the sidebar) I typically ignore when writing SO content. See this:

[image: Editing error message screenshot]

Can the error messages be placed differently, please? Somewhere in the "left, main column" of the site would be nice, I don't very much care where, exactly.

Comment: @Arjan ahh you're right, searching on meta just seems so damn hard, I'll leave my Q as a dupe hopefully it'll prevent others from posting a duplicate with wording similar to mine

Comment: Yep, [Don't exclude results because of quoted punctuation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164677/dont-exclude-results-because-of-quoted-punctuation) needs your vote!