# Allow wildcard in title search

Tags: feature-request, search

I am trying to find all questions that meet certain criteria and contain `Matlab` in the title. My original attempt was this:

```
title:"matlab" -[matlab*] is:question closed:no answers:0
```

However, it turns out this does not contain all results, for example not the ones containing `matlab:` (with colon). After this I tried various things including:

```
title:"matlab*" -[matlab*] is:question closed:no answers:0
```

But the only way to find this result was by using a colon in the search query. As a result I don't know whether I am missing other results, for example with `matlab-` or `MatlabToolbox` in the title.

---

So my question is: Can we get all results containing a certain word in the title?

---

I have searched around for a while but have found mostly questions about using wildcards in tags. The closest I have come is this: [Don't exclude results that have punctuation just because the query doesn't](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164677/dont-exclude-results-because-of-quoted-punctuation)

However, this question is different as it recommends "keyword" to find "keyword{punctuation}", whilst I would expect it to work at least for "keyword{wildcard}"