# How can I do a wildcard title search?

Tags: support, search

I am trying to find my posts whose titles contain `*idiom*`, where "*" means any characters, such as 'Is it **idiom**atic to say “grammatical and idiomatic”?'

I've tried `user:109190 title:idiom*`, `user:109190 title:*idiom*`, `user:109190 title:%idiom%`, none worked.

Could someone please give a hint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `title:` search operator doesn't support wildcards, so what you want is not possible: [Allow wildcard in title search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/195083/295232)

At least not with the regular site search; fortunately, we have the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com) which supports queries like [this one](https://data.stackexchange.com/ell/query/1215993/search-posts-by-user-and-partial-title?Query=idiom&UserId=109190):

[image]

Comment: Perhaps mention that the results can be up to a week out of date, as the underlying database is updated weekly (last time I checked). So this works well for historical searches, but not so great for real-time investigation of recent activity.

Comment: For real-time search  guess you could look at the demo box near the bottom of https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#order=desc&sort=activity&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true but ... some programming required.