# Quotation marks break exact phrase search

Tags: bug, search

Discussion on [this topic at Meta.Math](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/10791/1543) seems to suggest to me that *quoted* exact phrases will not match an exact phrase search. More precisely, the problem seems to be that searching for

```
"keyword string"
```

will match the text

```
keyword string
```

in the body or in the title, but not

```
"keyword string"
```

(with the quotes added) in the body or in the title. For example, compare [this output](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=too+many+edits+%5Bedit%5D+%5Brate-limiting%5D) with [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22too+many+edits%22+%5Bedit%5D+%5Brate-limiting%5D). One would expect the first two results in the first search by also found by the second search. But that is not the case.

This is a bug that should be fixed.

Comment: I think this matches [Don't exclude results because of quoted punctuation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164677/dont-exclude-results-because-of-quoted-punctuation).

Comment: @Arjan: I am not sure. For most other punctuation marks one can argue that they are part of the exact phrase. But I don't know of a way to search for the double quote character `"` at all!