# Search fails when original text includes backticks for formatting

Tags: bug, search, code-formatting

[A Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72933902/docker-getting-unknownhostexception-when-calling-an-api-on-another-container-us) including the following:

> `service1` has integration tests that needs to call the API on `service2`.

...or in its Markdown source:

> `` `service1` has integration tests that needs to call the API on `service2`. ``

...is not found when searching for, say:

- [service1 has integration tests that needs to call the API on service2](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=service1+has+integration+tests+that+needs+to+call+the+API+on+service2)
- [`service1` has integration tests that needs to call the API on `service2`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%60service1%60+has+integration+tests+that+needs+to+call+the+API+on+%60service2%60)

Even more, the above both return zero results, despite not even using quotes to search for part of a phrase.

It does work for, e.g.:

- ["has integration tests that needs to call the API on"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22has+integration+tests+that+needs+to+call+the+API+on%22)

This feels like a regression of [Don't exclude results that have punctuation just because the query doesn't](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164677/dont-exclude-results-that-have-punctuation-just-because-the-query-doesnt).

Answer (score 4):

Interestingly enough searching for

> [`service1` has integration tests that needs to call the API on](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%60service1%60+has+integration+tests+that+needs+to+call+the+API+on)

does produce a result, so the bug appears to be that search can't handle instances of 2 sets of code delimited words in the search.

Answer (score 4):

If you search for both the literals using [the supported search operator `code`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) the post shows up.

1. With all search elements:

   [`code:service1 "has integration tests that needs to call the API on" code:service2`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=code:service1+%22has+integration+tests+that+needs+to+call+the+API+on%22+code:service2&searchOn=3)
2. Using just the 2 code elements, and 3 words to narrow the results:

   [`code:service1 code:service2 integration tests need`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=code:service1+code:service2+integration+tests+need&searchOn=3)

---

---

I've asked myself the question in this thread many times before, so I'll add a few notes:

1. > or in its Markdown source:

   I don't think search uses Markdown (or CommonMark) it's just a [free text query string with its own search operators](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching). So to avoid additional confusion it's best to forget about the markup language SE uses for posts when working with search, with one notable exception: whatever is inside backticks (be it a [backtick string or code span](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/#code-spans)) can be queried directly using the `code:` search operator.
2. > This feels like a regression of [Don't exclude results that have punctuation just because the query doesn't.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164677/dont-exclude-results-that-have-punctuation-just-because-the-query-doesnt)

   I may be mistaken but I think in this specific example the issues are orthogonal because the backtick `` ` `` is a special case. I've never been able to understand why I have to remove the apostrophe `'` when searching for error messages that contain it (e.g. string literals).

My solution has been to split the text I'm searching for to remove the apostrophe but, as stated before, backticks shouldn't be thought of as punctuation when they're acting as CommonMark syntax, instead they act -in the context of SE's search- as scope delimiters to the `code:` search operator.

Comment: There are really two exceptions when searching body text, not just one. There's `code:` and `url:`. Both of those will return different results than a search for the text without those modifiers.

Comment: @Makyen I've also noticed in the meanwhile `code:` truncates the number so `service1` will return results with and without the trailing number.

Comment: Nice, good to know. And indeed in this very use case I suspected the original text to include code. (The spam filter on the Docker forums reported a newly posted topic as likely being a copy-paste action, so seeing the formatted text I likely knew what to search for exactly.) Regardless, in other searches I'd still expect my first two searches to also just disregard the formatting of the original text.